# Find the volume of the solid surrounded by planes x+2y+z=2, x=2y x=0 and z=0.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, volume

I don't understand when do we need polar coordinates or if we don't need them how to start solving this. I know we need to find volume of the small square inside of the solid by derivation by x and by y times the height. What should that be in this case?
[image: I used geogebra to visualize this.]

Comment: Is the answer 0?

Comment: What is what in your diagram? Is the green axis the $\;y\,-$ axis, or what?

Comment: @DonAntonio green is y asis yes and red one is x and blue is z.

Comment: @DavorMidenjak What is the answer?

Comment: @DavorMidenjak If green is $\;y\;$ and red is $\;x\;$ , where is the plane $\;x=2y\iff y=\frac x2\;$ ? This must be a plane whose projection on the $\;xy\,-$ plane is the corresponding line: an increasing one through the origin...I can't distinguish such a thing in that diagram.

Comment: @DonAntonio i used geogebra software and entered all the data and i got the image you see.